# Misclassification cost matrix on the Random Forest classifier implemented by Apache Spark (MLLIB)

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

I saw that the Random Forest classifier implemented by Apache Spark's MLLIB does not support a misclassification cost matrix for training and metric evaluation.

**QUESTIONS**: Is there a way to implement this without changing the MLLIB's code? How?

Each split on each tree should consider the cost matrix (e.g., [C5.0 cost matrix related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206091/how-to-set-costs-matrix-for-c5-0-package-in-r)).

Below is a part of a SCALA code for training and prediction using the [new] Random Forest classifer provided by MLLIB.

```
  [...]
  // Train a RandomForest model.
  // Here, I would like to insert a misclassification cost matrix
  val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
  .setFeaturesCol("rawFeatures")
  .setNumTrees(500)
  .setImpurity("gini")
  .setMaxBins(500)
  .setMaxDepth(30)
  .setFeatureSubsetStrategy("50")


  // Chain indexers and forest in a Pipeline
  val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(assembler,rf))

  // Train model.  This also runs the indexers.
  val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

  // Make predictions.
  val predictions = model.transform(testData)
  [...]
  // I could use predictions and the cost matrix to evaluate 
  // some metrics directly.
  [...]
```

Thank you in advance.

regards,

Paulo Angelo

Comment: did you find an answer